# JS array being overwritten by bolean values when being read

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

First time around here, and I'm an awful dev, so forgive in advance my possibly numerous mistakes :)

here's my issue: I'm trying to make a program that checks the proportions of each number from 1 to 9 in an array (I'm putting Benford's Law to the test), for that I have created 9 different variables (basically nX where X=1-9), I'm reading through my array with a for loop, and incrementing on each of my variables every time that the corresponding number is found (if array[i]= X, nX++), and I then console log my array. The issue is that on that console log, all values in my array are set to "1", which isn't the case prior to the execution of these few lines. So I'm not quite sure what happens, but I'm guessing that my "if" checks are returning "true" and changing the value of my array elements to 1 to reflect that.
So my question would be: any of you wise wizards know what I'm doing wrong and how to keep my data from being corrupted by this operation?

here's some code:

```
for (i = 0; i < benfordArrayProcessed.length; i++) {
  if (benfordArrayProcessed[i] = 1) {

    n1++;

  } else if (benfordArrayProcessed[i] = 2) {

    n2++;

  } else if (benfordArrayProcessed[i] = 3) {

    n3++;
  }
  [...]
```

Comment: You can use `===` (or `==`) for comparison. Using `=` is for assignment. Also, consider using an array of size 9 instead of individual variables, that way you can increment an array element at an index `n[benfordArrayProcessed[i]-1]++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your expression, you need use boolean expression instead of assignment, e.g. `if (benfordArrayProcessed[i] == 1)`. The values in the error get overwritten with because of assignment int he first statement itself and that's the reason you see 1 for all the elements.

Comment: F me, i'm an idiot... of course it's ==... Why brain, why do you have to make me loose so much time over nothing...
Well thanks heaps for your answer, you've saved a primate a lot of pointless head scratching.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the `==` usage, you can also chose to go for a `switch` statement:

```js
for (i = 0; i < benfordArrayProcessed.length; i++) {
  switch (benfordArrayProcessed[i]) {
    case 1:
      n1++;
      break;
    case 2:
      n2++;
      break;
    case 3:
      n3++;
      break;
    [...]
  }
}
```

Or, use an object with keys to up the numbers (a bit more tricky and depending on how you want to implement the rest of your code):

```js
const n = {
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
};

for (i = 0; i < benfordArrayProcessed.length; i++) {
  const num = benfordArrayProcessed[i];
  n[num]++;
}
```